# Появление блока по 1

Tags: jquery

Есть много одинаковых контейнеров, все они скрыты изначально, мне надо сделать так, что бы при клике на кнопку появлялся 1 из них, при клике еще 1 раз, появлялся еще 1 и тд., не могу придумать как это сделать.

```
<button>Добавить контент</button>
<div class="content"><input type ="text"></div>
<div class="content"><input type ="text"></div>
<div class="content"><input type ="text"></div>
<div class="content"><input type ="text"></div>



 .content {
      display: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var count = 0;
$('button').click(function(){
  $('.content').eq(count++).show();
})
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Добавить контент</button>
<div class="content"><input type="text"></div>
<div class="content"><input type="text"></div>
<div class="content"><input type="text"></div>
<div class="content"><input type="text"></div>
```

Comment: или `$('.content').not(':visible').first().show();` и без счетчика)

Comment: Можете оставить свой ответ)

Comment: Спасибо, прекрасно работает!